# Joomla 2.5 disable pagination?

Tags: pagination, components, joomla2.5

I built a component in joomla 2.5 (back end) and even if I don't include code for pagination, my results aren't displayed fully (they are limited to about 20). Is there a way where I can have all my results show on default? Or in other words disable pagination? Thanks!

Comment: Pls Check if its useful. http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/joomla-how-to-remove-pagination-from-the-featured-pagefrontpage/

Comment: Thanks but that's only for the front end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your list model, set the `list.limit` state accordingly. By default it will use the global list limit.
You can use this code in the populateState() function:

```
$this->setState('list.limit', 0);
```

Please note that if you call `parent::populateState($order, $dir);`, this will also set the `list.limit`. So you either don't call the parent function or your set the state after the parent function was called.

Answer (score 0):

firstly open your custom component view file, which is located in

/components/component_name/views/tmpl - file name is default.php and now comment this line

```
<?php echo $this->loadTemplate('_header'); ?>
```

and also

```
<?php echo $this->loadTemplate('_footer'); ?>
```

may very much help!

or another way is that goto joomla administrato - site - globle confi - Default List Limit
change limit

Comment: Thanks but the default list limit is only up to a 100..I need slightly more than that.